# SPA VUE LARAVEL 404 APACHE

Tags: laravel, vue.js, apache, single-page-application

Problem with SPA application, Laravel and Vue. Locally everything works fine, but there are errors when uploading to the server. All routes return a 404 error.

there are two dist packs with vue project and api folder with laravel project. for authorization and authentication, sanctum and fortufy are used.

My apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my.example.com/dist
    
    Alias "/api/"  "/var/www/my.example.com/api/public/"
    Alias "/sanctum/"  "/var/www/my.example.com/api/public/"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/my.example.com/api/public>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

.env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:eW5uwEwtWN8bTB3YztMSdQOEmiFw1VzwMBUpeEyjiZg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://my.example.com

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravelvue_org
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"


SESSION_DOMAIN=my.example.com
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=my.example.com
```

config/sanctum.php

```
<?php

return [

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
 'my.example.com,my.example.com/api,localhost:8080,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1,127.0.0.1:8080',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),



    'guard' => ['web'],



    'expiration' => null,


    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    ],

];
```

all requests return this error
error in browser

```
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php",
    "line": 43,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/CompiledRouteCollection.php",
            "line": 144,
            "function": "handleMatchedRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\AbstractRouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 673,
            "function": "match",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\CompiledRouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 662,
            "function": "findRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 651,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php",
            "line": 40,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
            "line": 86,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php",
            "line": 38,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 39,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 142,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 111,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/my.example.com/api/public/index.php",
            "line": 52,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

does anyone have any idea where the problem could be?

UPD:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: in on which operating system are you running ....this

Comment: @SaravanaSai Ubuntu 18.04.4 Apache 2.4 Php 7.4.4

Comment: have added this virtual host details in your etc/host file  . use this command in you terminal  'sudo nano /etc/hosts '  then add uour this virtual host site url to ip address .

look after this blog https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: @SaravanaSai i have real domain and real server

Comment: @SaravanaSai Everything works fine on the local computer. but when transferring to a real server and navigating through the domain, errors occur.

Comment: can ad the folder structure as an image on server

Comment: @SaravanaSai added in post